# Use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure to find an orthogonal basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&0\\-1&3&-1\\0&-1&2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\8\\-5 \end{pmatrix}$. So we can see $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

The question is: starting with the standard basis, use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure to find an A-orthogonal basis.

I'm not quite sure what this question is really asking me to do. I know Gram-Schmidt and I can use it to find the QR factorization but just don't know how to start here.

Comment: The the columns of the Q in the QR factorization give you the orthogonal basis.

Comment: @passerby51 ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) is well described on Wikipedia. A basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is $A$-orthogonal, if
$$
\text{for } i \not= j, \quad
\langle v_i, v_j \rangle_A = 0 \,,
$$
where
$$
\langle u, w \rangle_A = \langle A u, w \rangle = w^* A u
$$
is the $A$-inner product. The standard basis is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}, \dots
$$

What you have to do is as follows. Apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, as described on Wikipedia, to the standard basis. However instead of using the Euclidan inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ use the $A$-inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ when conducting the algorithm.